# How would one go about using D3 with emotion js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js, emotion

my current project is using TypeScript/React/Emotion, but we have need to implement D3 as well. How would I go about styling in D3? I can't use typical CSS files due to our linting rules. So I'm hoping I can figure it out in emotion js - is that possible or would I be better off just styling manually using D3?